# Como capturar esta excepción

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo un problema con una excepción, el caso es que no consigo capturarla y no se como hacerlo:

Tengo un modelo que hace una inserción en una base de datos:

```
xxxModel.generaNuevoxxx = async function (c, tipo, xxx) {

    let sql = `insert into xxx
        (xxx)
        values
        (xxx)`; 
    let obj = {
        xxx: xxx.xxx,
        xxx: xxx.xxx,
    }
    try {
        console.log(obj);
        return await c.execute(sql, obj, dbController.config);
    } catch (e) {
        throw new Error(`(xxx-model) generaNuevoxxxx -> ${e.message}`);
    }
}
```

El cual si ocurre una excepción en la ejecución de la inserción lanzaría la excepción.
Después tengo un controlador, que es algo más extenso:

```
async function fabricar(req, res) {
    let c;
    try {
       /*Aqui se hacen más cosas*/
       infoComponentes.map(async xxx => {
          try{
              let medidaxxx = calcularMedida(xxx);
              xxx.s1 = medidaxxx.stock_1;
              xxx.s2 = medidaxxx.stock_2;
              if (xxx.FAMILIA == 'xxxx' || xxx.FAMILIA == '<<<<') {
                  await xxxModel.generaMovimientoxxx(c, "qwe", [componente]);
                  await xxxModel.generaNuevoxxx(c, "qwe", xxx);
                ////AQUI ES DONDE LLAMO AL MODELO, EL CUAL AL DEVOLVER LA EXCEPCIÓN NO LA MANEJA
              }
          }catch(e){
            throw e;
          }
        });
      await c.commit();
      console.log("Desconectando...".red);
      return res.status(200).send({ message: "Proceso acabado." });
    }catch(e){
        c.rollback();
        console.log(`Error: (xxx) -> ${e.message}`);
        return res.status(500).send({ message: e.message });
    }
```

Me dice que la excepción está sin manejar y además llega al commit y finaliza mostrando el mensjae de proceso acabado. ¿De que manera podría capturar esa excepción?

Comment: Cambia los nombres de tus excepciones, tienes un `try...catch` anidado y debes darle nombre diferente a tus objetos `e` en el `catch`. Seguro el detalle está allí. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Habiendo cambiado los nombres de las excepciones no he podido llegar a obtener ningún cambio. Saludos.

Comment: Cual es la excepcion que te dice que esta sin manejar?

Comment: La que está dentro del map de info imponentes. Dentro del condicional. La cual llama al modelo.

Comment: *Me dice que la excepción está sin manejar...* ¿Quién?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr**

**Respuesta corta**

No uses un bloque anidado para intentar capturar un error de una función asíncrona que pasas como argumento a un metodo de un iterable (`map`), ya que el método `map` no es asíncrono. Por lo tanto la opción adecuada es manejar las promesas con [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/all).

**Respuesta larga con explicación y código de ejemplo al final**

El problema está en la forma en la que haces el manejo de la funciones asíncronas. Si bien estás usando `try...catch`, el procedimiento no se realiza de la forma que piensas.

Cuando realizas el llamado a: `infoComponentes.map(async xxx => {...});` efectivamente estás realizando un llamado a una función asíncrona que es la que se ejecuta por cada elemento de tu `array`, pero el método `map` de los tipo `Array` no es un método asíncrono.

Veamos un ejemplo:

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
//La siguiente función devuelve el doble de "number"
// es una función async porque devuelve una Promesa
const asyncDoubles = async (number) => {
  console.log(`Calculando ${number}.`);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`Devolviendo ${number} * 2.`);
      return resolve(number * 2);
    }, 2000);
  });
}
// llamamos al método map de numbers y le pasamos nuestra fucnión asíncrona
const doubles = numbers.map(asyncDoubles);
console.log(doubles);
console.log(`Esta es la línea final, después de esto no debería haber mas nada`);
```

Como puedes apreciar, el método `map` no se ejecuta de forma asíncrona, es decir, por cada elemento de `numbers` se ejecutará nuestra función `asyncDoubles`, pero se llamará a dicha función inmediatamente sin esperar que la llamada anterior a la misma devuelva un resultado.

Veamos lo que sucede ahora si lanzamos un error dentro de nuestra función asíncrona de acuerdo al resultado de la operación. Para eso usaremos `try...catch`.

```js
// nuestro array ahora contiene 6 números
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

// nuestra función no cambia en su declaración
const asyncDoubles = async (number) => {
  console.log(`Calculando ${number}.`);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // ahora intentaremos calcular el valor doble
      // e impondremos una condición
      // si la misma no se cumple, se lanzará un error
      try {
        if(number < 6) {
          console.log(`Devolviendo ${number} * 2.`);
          return resolve(number * 2);
        } else {
          throw new Error(`Número mayor que 5.`);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        // si en el bloque try se produce un error, el mismo será capturado aqui
        console.log(`Se captura el error: ${error.message}`);
        return reject(error);
      }
    }, 2000);
  });
}

// ahora veamos la secuencia de acontecimientos:
const doubles = numbers.map(asyncDoubles);
console.log(doubles);
console.log(`Esta es la línea final, después de esto no debería haber mas nada`);
```

Si ejecutáramos dicho código en Node, obtendríamos lo siguiente al final de nuestro código:

> `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Número mayor que 5.`

¿Porqué obtenemos este error?

Simplemente porque todo nuestro código ha sido ejecutado, no hay mas nada a procesar excepto lo que está en el `event loop` (nuestra función `setTimeout()`), la cual se ejecuta después de 2 segundos y en la cual se rechaza una promesa.

Sin embargo, ya no hay más código que procesar, el error se propaga hasta el proceso principal sin que haya un manejador (handler) para el mismo y es allí donde nos muestra el mensaje.

***¿Cómo es posible que `map` no sea asíncrono si lo llamo dentro de una función declarada con `async`?***

En tu código llamas al método `map` dentro de una función asíncrona: `async function fabricar(req, res) {...}` ¿debería ser asíncrono ahora?

Veamos un ejemplo de comportamiento usando `map` dentro de una función `async`:

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const asyncDoubles = async (number) => {
  console.log(`Calculando ${number}.`);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      try {
        if(number < 6) {
          console.log(`Devolviendo ${number} * 2.`);
          return resolve(number * 2);
        } else {
          throw new Error(`Número mayor que 5.`);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Se captura el error: ${error.message}`);
        return reject(error);
      }
    }, 2000);
  });
}

// declaramos una función async y llamamos a map dentro de la misma
const calcularDobles = async () => {
  const result = numbers.map(asyncDoubles);
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

// llamamos a nuestra función async
const doubles = calcularDobles();
console.log(doubles);
console.log(`Esta es la línea final, después de esto no debería haber mas nada`);
```

Pues es el mismo comportamiento.

Sin embargo no hemos usado `await`. ¿Será que debemos usarlo?

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const asyncDoubles = async (number) => {
  console.log(`Calculando ${number}.`);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      try {
        if(number < 6) {
          console.log(`Devolviendo ${number} * 2.`);
          return resolve(number * 2);
        } else {
          throw new Error(`Número mayor que 5.`);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Se captura el error: ${error.message}`);
        return reject(error);
      }
    }, 2000);
  });
}

const calcularDobles = async () => {
  const result = await numbers.map(asyncDoubles);
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

const doubles = calcularDobles();
console.log(doubles);
console.log(`Esta es la línea final, después de esto no debería haber mas nada`);
```

Pues nada. Seguimos obteniendo el mismo resultado. Se agotan los recursos, por lo tanto veamos la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) de `async function` para obtener una respuesta: (traducción propia)

> Una función `async` es una función que opera de forma asíncrona por medio del `event loop` usando una Promesa implícita para devolver su resultado.
>
> Una función `async` puede contener la expresión `await` que pausa la ejecución de la función asíncrona y espera la resolución de la **Promesa** pasada, y luego reanuda la ejecución de la función `async` y devuelve el valor resuelto.

Y aquí está todo el misterio: `await` tampoco convierte una función síncrona (como `map`) en una función `asíncrona`. Lo que hace `await` es esperar a que la función que se ejecutará (`map`) devuelva un resultado y luego continuará con la ejecución de la función `async`. El método `map` no devuelve una Promesa, por lo tanto `await` solo pausa un instante que es lo que tarda `map` en llamar a la función `asyncDoubles`, y continúa su camino sin esperar que las llamadas a `asyncDoubles` resuelvan la Promesa.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Ya vimos que usar `async` para realizar lo que intentamos no es una opción, ya que el método `map` no es asíncrono.

Debemos refactorizar nuestro código. Actualmente según lo que expones en tu pregunta, puedo entender el proceso de lo que intentas llevar a cabo.

Me he dado la tarea de crear un ejemplo lo más parecido para que se pueda reproducir con las herramientas aquí disponibles. El código sería el siguiente:

```js
// el siguiente JSON emula a request
const req = {
  body: {
    componentes: [
      { name: 'Componente 1', status: 'No procesado' },
      { name: 'Componente 2', status: 'No procesado' },
      { name: 'Componente 3', status: 'No procesado' },
      { name: 'Componente 4', status: 'No procesado' },
      { name: 'Componente 5', status: 'No procesado' }
    ]
  }
}

// el siguiente JSON emula a response
const res = {
  send: function(object) {
    console.log(object);
  }
}

// El siguiente JSON emula a Model según tu definición
const Model = {
  generarNuevo: async (componente) => {
    try {
      await execute(componente);
    } catch(error) {
      throw new Error(`Error en generarNuevo: ${error.message} al procesar ${componente.name}.`);
    }
  }
}

// la siguiente función emula a c.commit
const commit = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const fail = false;
      if(fail) {
        console.log(`Rejecting commit`);
        return reject(new Error(`Not Commited.`));
      }
      console.log(`Resolving commit`);
      return resolve(`Commited.`);
    }, 1000);
  });
}


// la siguiente función emula a c.execute
const execute = async (componente) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`Procesando: ${componente.name}.`);
      if(componente.name !== 'Componente 5') {
        componente.status = 'Procesado';
        return resolve(componente);
      } else {
        return reject(new Error(`Promesa no resuelta`));
      }
    }, 2000);
  });
}

// la siguiente función emula al método fabricar del controlador
const fabricar = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let infoComponentes = req.body.componentes;
    infoComponentes.map(async (componente) => {
      console.log(`infoComponentes.map: ${componente.name}`);
      try {
        await Model.generarNuevo(componente);
      } catch(e) {
        console.log(`Error en map: ${e.message}`);
        throw e;
      }
    });
    await commit();
    console.log('Deconectando...');
    res.send({
      message: 'Proceso finalizado satisfactoriamente.'
    });
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    res.send({
      message: error.message
    });
  }
}

fabricar(req,res);
```

Pues ya hemos reproducido el error, y veremos que al ejecutar este código en Node, obtendremos el siguiente error:

> `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error en generarNuevo: Promesa no resuelta al procesar Componente 5.`

Sin embargo antes de obtener dicho error, podremos ver en consola lo siguiente:

```
Resolving commit
Deconectando...
{ message: 'Proceso finalizado satisfactoriamente.' }
```

Es decir, el bloque `catch` que debería atrapar nuestra excepción no lo hace. Y ya vimos el porqué anteriormente.

Aquí viene la refactorización, habiendo entendido un poco lo que pretendes con tu código.

El proceso que creo quieres realizar sería el siguiente:

1. Dada una lista de "Componentes", realizar una serie de operaciones con cada uno.
2. Después de completado el paso 1 con cada item de la lista, guardar el "Componente" en la base de datos.
3. Una vez que todos los componentes hayan sido guardados, realizar un `commit` en la base de datos.
4. Informar de los resultados (sean positivos o negativos).

En pocas palabras estás realizando un [`bulk insert`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL#BULK_INSERT) en tu base de datos.

Dado que el método `map` no es asíncrono, debemos buscar una alternativa para realizar la inserción de los registros en la base de datos.

Una alternativa, para no alterar tanto la forma en la que estamos intentando realizar las cosas es usar [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/all).

Básicamente, este método devuelve una Promesa, la cual se resuelve satisfactoriamente si todas las promesas del argumento iterable son concluidas con éxito, y se rechaza en caso que alguna promesa del argumento iterable sea rechazada.

La implementación sería la siguiente:

```js
// elementos req y res sin alteración

const req = {
  body: {
    componentes: [
      { name: 'Componente 1', status: 'No procesado' },
      { name: 'Componente 2', status: 'No procesado' },
      { name: 'Componente 3', status: 'No procesado' },
      { name: 'Componente 4', status: 'No procesado' },
      { name: 'Componente 5', status: 'No procesado' }
    ]
  }
}

const res = {
  send: function(object) {
    console.log(object);
  }
}

// Sin cambios en el método generarNuevo
const Model = {
  generarNuevo: async (componente) => {
    try {
      // realizamos operaciones con el componente antes de guardarlo
      await execute(componente);
    } catch(error) {
      throw new Error(`Error en generarNuevo: ${error.message}`);
    }
  }
}

// tampoco hay cambios en execute() ni en commit()
const execute = async (componente) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`Procesando: ${componente.name}.`);
      if(componente.name !== 'Componente 5') {
        componente.status = 'Procesado';
        resolve(componente);
      } else {
        reject(new Error(`Error procesando ${componente.name}`));
      }
    }, 2000);
  });
}

const commit = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const fail = false;
      if(fail) {
        console.log(`Rejecting commit`);
        return reject(new Error(`Not Commited.`));
      }
      console.log(`Resolving commit`);
      return resolve(`Commited.`);
    }, 1000);
  });
}

// implementamos Promise.all en nuestro método fabricar()
const fabricar = (req, res) => {
  let infoComponentes = req.body.componentes;
  // almacenamos el array de componentes en un nuevo array y le llamaremos promises (tendrá promesas)
  let promises = infoComponentes.map((componente) => {
    // dado que generarNuevo es asícrona podemos usar then y catch
    return Model.generarNuevo(componente)
      .then(() => {
        console.log(`Promesa resuelta para: ${componente.name}.`);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        throw new Error(e.message);
      });
  });

  // Ahora llamamos a Promise.all() y le pasamos nuestro array de promesas
  Promise.all(promises)
    .then(async () => {
      // si todas las promesas son resueltas podemos hacer commit
      // sin embargo, el commit podría fallar, habría
      // que envolverlo en un bloque `try catch`
      try {
        await commit();
        console.log('Deconectando...');
        console.log('Enviado respuesta a cliente:');
        res.send({
          message: 'Proceso finalizado satisfactoriamente.'
        });
      } catch (err) { // <- Aqui capturo errores en el commit
        console.log(err.message);
        console.log('Enviado respuesta a cliente:');
        res.send({
          message: `Error durante el proceso: ${err.message}`
        });
      }
      
    })
    .catch((error) => { // <- Aqui capturo errores en los execute de cada componente
      console.log(error.message);
      console.log('Enviado respuesta a cliente:');
      res.send({
        message: `Error en proceso: ${error.message}`
      });
    });
}

fabricar(req,res);
```

Ahora, ya tenemos listo nuestro `bulk insert` usando promesas y programación asíncrona.

Si ejecutamos el código anterior en Node los posibles resultados serían:

***Con error en el Componente 5***

```
//se cumple: componente.name === 'Componente 5'

Error en generarNuevo: Error procesando Componente 5
Enviado respuesta a cliente:
{ message: 'Error en proceso: Error en generarNuevo: Error procesando Componente 5' }
```

***Sin error en componentes pero error en commit***

```
// se cumple: fail === true

Rejecting commit
Not Commited.
Enviado respuesta a cliente:
{ message: 'Error durante el proceso: Not Commited.' }
```

***Sin error en componentes y sin error en commit***

```
Resolving commit
Deconectando...
Enviado respuesta a cliente:
{ message: 'Proceso finalizado satisfactoriamente.' }
```

Espero que esta respuesta deje claras tus dudas y te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Mauricio Contreras!!! Una respuesta perfecta !!! Mi problema está solucionado. La respuesta es extensa y se puede entender perfectamente. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Cuando ejecutas el método `.map(...)`, le estás pasando una función asíncrona. Es decir, es una función que devuelve una promesa. Es similar (no igual) a usar un `setTimeout`:

```js
function a() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    throw new Error('Error');
  });
}

try {
  a();
} catch (error) {
  console.log('Error capturado',error);
}
console.log('Ejecución completada');
```

El error no se captura porque durante el `try - catch` no se ejecuta `a()`, simplemente se *declara* ( o se delega, como prefieras verlo) que se ejecutará en un futuro próximo.

Usando promesas sería algo así:

```js
async function  a1() {
  return new Promise(function (a, r) {
    setTimeout(()=> {
      throw new Error()
    });
  });
}

async function  a2() {
  return new Promise(function (a, r) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      r('se llamó a reject');
    });
  });
}
async function m1() {
  try {
    await a1();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error',error);
  }
  console.log('Ejecución 1 completada');
}

async function m2() {
  try {
     await a2();
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error capturado',error);
  }
  console.log('Ejecución 2 completada');
}
m1();
m2();
```

**Tenemos dos escenarios**: se ha lanzado un error desde dentro de la promesa (en `a1`) o el error fue reconocido y simplemente se llamó a función de *rejection* (en `a2`).
Al usar await, el código se queda esperando a la resolución de la promesa, pero si ésta lanza un error, no se puede capturar. Si llama a reject, se interpreta como un *error asíncrono* que se puede tratar dentro de la función asíncrona

Por tanto podemos ver que si se manejan bien las promesas y las excepciones, podemos capturar los errores.

¿Qué ocurre con tu código? Tienes un array de promesas que **no gestionas** de ningún modo, con lo que los errores no se pueden capturar. Es lo que hace map: crea un array con el mismo número de elementos que array recorrido, generados por la función que le has pasado.

La solución es usar Promise.all():

```
await Promise.all(misDatos.map(await () => ...));
```

```js
async function porDos(n) {
  if (n<2) {
    console.log('Da', n * 2);
    return 2*n;
  }
  throw new Error('Nah');
}

async function main () {
  try {
    await Promise.all([0,1,2].map(porDos));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Ooops!',e.toString());
  }
}

main();
```